# Conjecture about expected distance between two points in a regular polygon

Tags: geometry, optimization, expected-value, polygons, conjectures

Point $P$ is a uniformly random point on the perimeter of a regular polygon.
Point $C$ is a fixed point somewhere on the circle inscribed in the polygon.
Is the following conjecture true:

> The expected distance between $C$ and $P$ is maximized when $C$ is where the circle touches the polygon.

Numerical investigation shows that the conjecture is true for a square.

Suppose the square has vertices $(\pm1,\pm1)$. $C$ has coordinates $(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$.

$E(PC)=\frac18\left(\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{(\cos\theta-x)^2+(\sin\theta+1)^2}dx+\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{(\cos\theta-1)^2+(\sin\theta-y)^2}dy+\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{(\cos\theta-x)^2+(\sin\theta-1)^2}dx+\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{(\cos\theta+1)^2+(\sin\theta-y)^2}dy\right)$

Here is the graph of $E(PC)$ against $\theta$ for $0\le \theta \le \pi/2$.

[image]

The graph shows that $E(PC)$ is maximized when $\theta=0$, i.e. when $C$ is where the circle touches the square.

Is my conjecture true for all regular polygons?

Comment: Interesting. The continuity as a function of $C$ and the symmetry of the polygon implies local extrema for $E(PC)$ for $C$ at the vertices and the midpoints of the sides. It should be easy  to check that the value at the vertices is larger. That should be a proof - if not for the two local minima in your picture. Where do they come from?

Comment: @EthanBolker $C$ is on the circle inscribed in the polygon, so $C$ cannot be a vertex of the polygon.

Comment: I misread, thinking of the circumcircle. But the symmetry argument still works. The midpoints of the sides and the intersections of the radii to the vertices should be local extrema. Why are there two others?

Comment: @EthanBolker Good question; I don't have an intuitive explanation for the existence of the two others. (The symmetry argument does not tell us that they cannot exist.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a script to estimate $E(PC)$ for various choices of $C$.

Let $n$ be the number of sides. It appears that for $n \leq 5$, your conjecture is true and that for $n\geq6$, $E(PC)$ is maximised when $C$ is collinear with the center and a vertex. I have no idea why.

Here's the Python code if it's useful to anyone:

```
from numpy import cos,pi,exp,mean,argmax
M=2000

for n in [3,4,5,7,8]:
    d=1/cos(pi/n)
    verts = [d*exp(2j*pi*k/n) for k in range(n)]+[d]
    ps=[i/M*verts[k]+(1-i/M)*verts[k+1] for i in range(M) for k in range(n)]
    cs=[exp(a/10*pi*1j/n) for a in range(11)]

    print(n,argmax([mean([abs(c-p) for p in ps]) for c in cs]))
```